# how to successively increment a 2-dimensional list

Tags: python

Part of this assignment deals with a 1-dimensional list and a 2-dimensional list. The 2-D list has 10 rows, with 4 elements each; the 1-D list has 4 elements.

The assignments calls for copying the `gamma` list (see code) into the first row of the `inStock` list. Then each row after the first needs to be successively incremented by 3. By successively i mean multiplying everything in the first row of inStock by three and storing those values in the second row, then taking the values stored in the second row multiplying those by three and storing those values in the third row of inStock, and so on.

I understand how to copy `gamma` but I am having trouble figuring out how to increment based off the previous list.

I am having difficulty creating a function that increments `inStock` successively.

This is what I have done. It increases the elements in gamma by three and stores them into the first row of inStock. But all the while loop does is take the values from the first row of inStock and store them into the other rows, rather than increment them successively.

```py
row = 10
col = 4
gamma = [11, 13, 15, 17]
inStock = [[0] * col] * row

def copyGamma(listG, gamma):
    listG[0] = gamma.copy()
    x = 0

    while x < 9:
        x +=1
        listG[x] = [i * 3 for i in listG[0]]
    return listG

retList = copyGamma(inStock, gamma)
print(retList)
```

```
#this is the output of the above code

11      13      15      17 #this is inStock[0]
33      39      45      51 #this is inStock[1]
33      39      45      51 #this is inStock[2]
33      39      45      51
33      39      45      51
33      39      45      51
33      39      45      51
33      39      45      51
33      39      45      51
33      39      45      51


#This is the output i am looking for, format does not matter:

11      13      15      17  #This is inStock[0]

33      39      45      51  #This is inStock[1]

99      117     135     153  #This *should* be inStock[2]

297     351     405     459 #and so on

891     1053    1215    1377

2673    3159    3645    4131

8019    9477    10935   12393

24057   28431   32805   37179

72171   85293   98415   111537

216513  255879  295245  334611
```

Comment: Please format your code properly. Use the edit button beneath the question, and follow the formatting instructions that are shown.

Comment: What does "I am having difficulty creating a function that increments inStock more generally" mean? What issue do you run into? What does your code do instead of the thing you want? How would you like to generate the increments exactly? All that information should be in your question.

Comment: `inStock = [[0] * col] * row` will almost certainly not behave the way you expect. Use `inStock = [[0] * col for _ in range(row)]` instead.

Comment: You've tagged your question with both Python-3.x and Python-2.7. You're *probably* not using both for this code (which doesn't seem to be about porting from one version to another), so can you please remove whichever one is not relevant?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list comprehension and the fact that each row's elements are effectively multiplied by a power of 3:

```
inStock = [[x * 3**i for x in gamma] for i in range(row)]
```